# Why turbo boost may not work?

Tags: 16.10, intel, cpu, turbo-boost

I have an Intel Core i5-7600 (not K) CPU and a B250 Gigabyte motherboard (GA-B250M-D3H to be specific) with the latest BIOS update. The Turbo Boost feature is enabled in the BIOS. However, this is what I get using `turbostat` on Ubuntu 16.10 while running some computational heavy operations (e.g. `openssl speed`):

```
 CPU Avg_MHz   Busy% Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz
   -    1045   29.83    3500    3506
   0     245    7.00    3500    3508
   1     213    6.08    3500    3507
   2     222    6.33    3500    3507
   3    3500  100.00    3500    3504
```

The CPU should be running at 4.1 GHz in Turbo Boost, but it's using its base frequency.  What can cause this? Are there any other factors that can prevent Turbo Boost from working?

## Update:

Here's the `turbostat --debug` output:

```
CPUID(0): GenuineIntel 22 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:9e:9 (6:158:9)
CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR SMX EIST TM2 TSC MSR ACPI-TM TM
CPUID(6): APERF, DTS, PTM, HWP, HWPnotify, HWPwindow, HWPepp, No-HWPpkg, No-EPB
cpu0: MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE: 0x00850089 (TCC EIST MONITOR)
CPUID(7): SGX
cpu0: MSR_IA32_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00000005 (Locked )
CPUID(0x15): eax_crystal: 2 ebx_tsc: 292 ecx_crystal_hz: 0
TSC: 3504 MHz (24000000 Hz * 292 / 2 / 1000000)
CPUID(0x16): base_mhz: 3500 max_mhz: 2800 bus_mhz: 100
cpu0: MSR_MISC_PWR_MGMT: 0x00001cc0 (ENable-EIST_Coordination DISable-EPB)
RAPL: 4033 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 65 Watts
cpu0: MSR_PLATFORM_INFO: 0x8080838f1012300
8 * 100 = 800 MHz max efficiency frequency
35 * 100 = 3500 MHz base frequency
cpu0: MSR_IA32_POWER_CTL: 0x0038005d (C1E auto-promotion: DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x1c1c1c1c
28 * 100 = 2800 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
28 * 100 = 2800 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
28 * 100 = 2800 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
28 * 100 = 2800 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
cpu0: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_NOMINAL: 0x00000023 (base_ratio=35)
cpu0: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_1: 0x00000000 ()
cpu0: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_2: 0x00000000 ()
cpu0: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_CONTROL: 0x80000000 ( lock=1)
cpu0: MSR_TURBO_ACTIVATION_RATIO: 0x00000000 (MAX_NON_TURBO_RATIO=0 lock=0)
cpu0: MSR_NHM_SNB_PKG_CST_CFG_CTL: 0x7e000006 (UNdemote-C3, UNdemote-C1, demote-C3, demote-C1, UNlocked: pkg-cstate-limit=6: pc8)
cpu0: MSR_PM_ENABLE: 0x00000001 (HWP)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_CAPABILITIES: 0x010f2329 (high 0x29 guar 0x23 eff 0xf low 0x1)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_REQUEST: 0x80002909 (min 0x9 max 0x29 des 0x0 epp 0x80 window 0x0 pkg 0x0)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_INTERRUPT: 0x00000000 (Dis_Guaranteed_Perf_Change, Dis_Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_STATUS: 0x00000004 (No-Guaranteed_Perf_Change, No-Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT: 0x000a0e03 (0.125000 Watts, 0.000061 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_INFO: 0x00000208 (65 W TDP, RAPL 0 - 0 W, 0.000000 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x42ffd0001aea82 (UNlocked)
cpu0: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (3408.250000 Watts, 8.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: PKG Limit #2: ENabled (4090.000000 Watts, 0.002441* sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_DRAM_POWER_LIMIT: 0x148ffa00148ffa (UNlocked)
cpu0: DRAM Limit: ENabled (511.250000 Watts, 1.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x00641400 (100 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_STATUS: 0x88390000 (43 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_THERM_STATUS: 0x883c0000 (40 C +/- 1)
cpu1: MSR_IA32_THERM_STATUS: 0x883a0000 (42 C +/- 1)
cpu2: MSR_IA32_THERM_STATUS: 0x88390000 (43 C +/- 1)
cpu3: MSR_IA32_THERM_STATUS: 0x88370000 (45 C +/- 1)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC3_IRTL: 0x0000884e (valid, 79872 ns)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC6_IRTL: 0x00008876 (valid, 120832 ns)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC7_IRTL: 0x00008894 (valid, 151552 ns)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC8_IRTL: 0x000088fa (valid, 256000 ns)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC9_IRTL: 0x0000894c (valid, 339968 ns)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC10_IRTL: 0x00008bf2 (valid, 1034240 ns)
    Core     CPU Avg_MHz   Busy% Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz     IRQ     SMI  CPU%c1  CPU%c3  CPU%c6  CPU%c7 CoreTmp  PkgTmp Totl%C0  Any%C0  GFX%C0 CPUGFX% Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 Pkg%pc7 Pkg%pc8 Pkg%pc9 Pk%pc10 PkgWatt RAMWatt   PKG_%   RAM_%
       -       -    1231   35.15    3500    3506    3143       0    5.87    0.05    0.83   58.14      45      45  141.15  100.08    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   23.02    1.19    0.00    0.00
       0       0     337    9.62    3500    3509     576       0   10.83    0.08    1.20   78.28      34      45  141.05  100.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   23.02    1.19    0.00    0.00
       1       1     502   14.32    3500    3509     653       0    3.39    0.08    1.18   81.04      34
       2       2    3499  100.00    3500    3503    1336       0    0.11    0.00    0.00    0.00      45
       3       3     585   16.73    3500    3503     578       0    9.14    0.02    0.96   73.16      36
```

Strangely enough `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo` returns `1` even though I double checked that "Intel Turbo Boost Technology" is enabled in the BIOS. And I can't change this file manually.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add some lines from turbostat in --debug mode. In particular the lines that say the maximum frequencies as a function of active cores. Example: `cpu1: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x23242526` and `37 * 100.0 = 3700.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores`. And is turbo enabled? Do: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`

Comment: @DougSmythies I provided some additional information. Turns out that turbo is indeed disabled, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: O.K., well nothing makes sense. I suspect, but am not sure, you need the very newest version of turbostat, which just came out two days ago as part of kernel 4.11-rc1. For a test, and because your processor is so new, you might want to try kernel 4.11-rc1 from the [Ubuntu mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11-rc1/). That will not solve your turbostat issue, as it needs to be compiled from source, but one thing at a time.

Comment: Sadly it seems like the new kernel does not support my GPU, so the resolution has broken and I couldn't log into my desktop environment.  I rolled back to the old kernel. I hope that new updates (for either BIOS or Ubuntu itself) will fix that. For now I have to wait, I guess. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, there were some issues with HWP (HardWare Pstate). I don't know if they apply to your case or not, but you could try booting with HWP disabled (intel_pstate=no_hwp in grub on the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line. But yes, sometimes with such new processors you have to wait for linux to catchup.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry! I should've checked my motherboard's website before posting this question. They released a new BIOS update just a couple weeks ago with "V core voltage adjust". I updated the BIOS and now everything works.

Comment: Spent a few minutes reading question and comments to learn it was BIOS issue already fixed. VTC as unreproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was just a BIOS problem. For those of you who also have similar hardware, please, update your BIOS to the latest version (even if you think you have the latest one, check anyway :)). Also, try disabling XMP if you have it enabled and see if it works.